# complex numbers - proving both sides are equal

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to do the following problem:

Let $z, w$ be complex numbers. Prove that if $\operatorname{Re}(z \bar w) = 2,$ then

$$| z-w |^4 = |z|^4 + |w|^4 + 2| z|^2|w|^2 -8|z|^2 -8| w|^2+ 16.$$

Can anyone tell me how to use $\operatorname{Re}(s) = 1/2(s + \bar s)$ to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$$
 |  z - w |^2 = (z-w)(\bar z - \bar w) = |z|^2 + |w|^2 - 2 \operatorname{Re} (z \bar w)
$$
which holds for all complex numbers $z, w$.

Then use that $\operatorname{Re}(z \bar w) = 2$, and square again.